# How to deploy pytorch in docker image?

Tags: docker, anaconda, pytorch

I want to deploy pytorch on a docker image. Is there a way that I can do that? I faced so much problems installing pytorch, their official installation links does not seem to be working; neither pip/conda works. Does anyone have any alternative solution in installing pytorch?

Comment: really!! according to me, installing pytorch is the simplest among all deep learning libraries !!

Answer (score 1):

You can find pytorch images on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=pytorch&starCount=1).

If those images are not sufficient, you can check their Dockerfiles to see how you can build you own custom image.